# Neo4j.rb: how to search from serialize property having array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher, neo4j.rb

```
class Picture

  property :name
  property :user_ids

  serialize :user_ids
end

Picture.create(name: '1', user_ids: [1,4,5])
```

How to find all pictures having user id 1 in user_ids property

I am trying this in way:

```
Picture.as(:p).where('ALL(x IN [1] WHERE x IN p.user_ids)')
```

Neo4j.rb version -     `neo4j (8.0.13)`
Neo4j - `3.1.1 Enterprise`

But its not working. Or there is any better way to store array and query it as well, Any help would be very appreciable

---

*EDIT: Shown Bruno's Example & My Node description above I have used example node*

[image]

@Bruno example is working fine.

**Here is my Neo4j node view**

[image]

`match (p:Place) where ALL(x IN [14] WHERE x IN p.from_airport_ids) return p`

This is not working in my case

```
class Place
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :name
  property :from_airport_ids
  serialize :from_airport_ids
end
```

Create Place through API

```
{  
  "place":{  
    "name":"Name",
    "from_airport_ids":[14,44,67]
  }
}
```

Is it related to how my array values stored in node and how @Bruno example values are  stored?

Comment: Bruno's solution is probably the best, but I suspect that the reason your solution isn't working is because you're using `ALL`.  I think that `ANY` would work better

Comment: @BrianUnderwood I created a node with `create(:Picture{name: '1', user_ids: [1,4,5]})`, performed the query `MATCH (p) where ALL(x IN [1] WHERE x IN p.user_ids)
return p` and worked. But I agree with you that the approach using the IN operator is at least more readable.

Comment: @BrianUnderwood Maybe has some error message not informed

Comment: I edited the Question and gave more info I can see the example @bruno gave is working fine. But in my case there is difference how array values stored in node [1,2,3] vs 1,23

Comment: @BrianUnderwood I  think issue is in Neo4j.rb  when I use serialize to store array, it is getting stored as string in neo4j. so I am not able to query it.. If I remove serialize and then save, it is storing  as array in neo4j but when I find it like `Place.find(uuid)`  it is giving error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String` in Neo4j lib

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your query to:

```
Picture.as(:p).where('1 IN p.user_ids)')
```

That is: match all `p`s where `p.user_ids` contains 1.

Also, I believe you should store relationships between `:User` and `:Picture` nodes instead of an array of ids into `:Picture`. It's a more *graph-way* to do things.

Something like

```
            -[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:User {id:1})
          /
(:Picture)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:User {id:2})
          \
            -[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:User {id:3})
```

Comment: I have edited the question, above query is also not working, your example (in comment) works good, Also I have given real Node description in question. Picture, user were just examples, But thanks for explaning it

Comment: @V.G `I created a node with` create (:Place { name:"Name", from_airport_ids:[14,44,67]}) and ran the query `match (p:Place) where ALL(x IN [14] WHERE x IN p.from_airport_ids) return p`
it's returns me node. It's not the desired behavior?

Comment: When I create the node directly form neo4j console then query works good, but when I create it through Active::Node then same query is not working, I uploaded snapshot in chatroom